# creating a table with Foreign key in it gives error ORA-00904: : invalid identifier in oracle 10g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

[Image of the code with table, query and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqPyW.png)

I have oracle 10g installed on my computer. I have created a table in it named STUDENT and this STUDENT table has a primary key called RNO and now I want to create another table named FEE and make this RNO key into a foreign key in FEE table with the following query:

```
CREATE TABLE FEE ( RNO NUMBER(2), Amount number(20) Not Null, Date varchar2(10) Not Null, Receipt Number(10) Not Null, CONSTRAINT FEEFK FOREIGN KEY (RNO) REFERENCES STUDENT (RNO));
```

Now I have done all I could to correct it but just can't seem to find any problem or error with this query above. The Query gives the following error in Oracle 10g:

> ORA-00904: : invalid identifier

Comment: As per the duplicate, you can't have a reserved (unquoted) keyword as a column name; either change the `DATE` column to another name or use double-quotes `"DATE"` to indicate that it is a (case-sensitive) identifier but this latter option may cause issues down the line as you'll need to quote it everywhere you use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Column name can't be `DATE`, it is reserved for datatype. Rename it to, say, `CDATE`.

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE student (rno NUMBER (2) PRIMARY KEY);

Table created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE FEE
  2  (
  3     RNO      NUMBER (2),
  4     Amount   NUMBER (20) NOT NULL,
  5     cDate    VARCHAR2 (10) NOT NULL,
  6     Receipt  NUMBER (10) NOT NULL,
  7     CONSTRAINT FEEFK FOREIGN KEY (RNO) REFERENCES STUDENT (RNO)
  8  );

Table created.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use double qoutes "Date" or rename your column Date as some other name like DateColumn as Date is a reserved name fpr date types in oracle

Comment: Brackets? For Oracle? I don't think so.

Comment: @Littlefoot ahh i get it brackets in case of sql server and double qoutes for oracle

Comment: Btw @MuhammadKashif Invalid identifier means issue with the column name as the identifier date  is not valid